# How can I find the number of business days in the current month with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I create a function for finding the number of business days (weekdays) of the current month? Can you code in simple JavaScript without [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)?

```
    function daysInMonth(iMonth, iYear)
    {
        return 32 - new Date(iYear, iMonth, 32).getDate();
    }

    function Detail()
    {
        var d = new Date();
        var year = d.getFullYear();
        var month = d.getMonth();
        var dim = daysInMonth(month, year);
        alert(dim);
    }

    function Businessday(iMonth, iYear)
    {
        // Enter code here
    }

    function isBusinessDay()
    {
        var d = new Date();
        var day = d.getDay();
        switch(day) {
            case 0:
                document.write("Today is weekend");
            break;

            case 6:
                document.write("Today is weekend");
                break;

            default:
                document.write("Today is a business day");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what difference, if any, there is between a business day and a week day (monday - friday)?

Comment: Monday - Friday is Business day.

Comment: [Documentation for getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OK, let's solve this one piece at a time.

The [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object in JavaScript has a method, [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay). This will return 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, ... 6 for Saturday. Given that, we can conclude that we want to not count days whose `getDay` returns 0 or 6.

You already have a function to return the number of days in a month, so assuming that, we can loop over all of the days and check the result of getDay. `daysInMonth` makes the assumption that the month is zero-based; so 0 = January.

I'd encourage you to try solving this on your own from here; otherwise read on.

---

Let's start with an `isWeekday` function. We need the year, month, and day:

```
function isWeekday(year, month, day) {
    var day = new Date(year, month, day).getDay();
    return day !=0 && day !=6;
}
```

We do exactly as we talked about above: we construct a Date, and use `getDay` to determine if it's a day.

Now we need to loop over all of the days in the month:

```
function getWeekdaysInMonth(month, year) {
    var days = daysInMonth(month, year);
    var weekdays = 0;
    for(var i=0; i< days; i++) {
        if (isWeekday(year, month, i+1))
            weekdays++;
    }
    return weekdays;
}
```

We loop over all of the days in the month. We add 1 when checking `isWeekday` because the day, unlike month, is 1 based. If it is, we increment `weekdays`, then return.

So we can use `getWeekdaysInMonth` like this:

```
var weekdays = getWeekdayInMonth(9, 2011); // 9 = October.
```

Which will result in 21.

Answer (score 4):

Arrow function style with chaining:

```
(
    (year, month) => 
        new Array(32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate())
        .fill(1)
        .filter(
            (id, index) =>
                [0, 6].indexOf(
                    new Date(year, month, index + 1).getDay()) === -1
                ).length
)(2017, 5)
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order (or at least some references). For example, why the magic numbers 1, +1, and -1? Why fill() and filter()? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44262524/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: The indentation in current answer is misleading: nested arrow function part reads as "length of (index or boolean equality test tesult)", which is surprising.  Also you could use [`.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of index comparison for semantic reasons.