# How to display total workdays in month and current workday javascript

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

Was searching for a solution to display the current workday over the total workdays in the current month. Workdays in this case are defined as **Mon**, **Tues**, **Wed**, **Thurs**, & **Fri**.

Closest solution I found was this: [How to find business days in current month with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827838/how-to-find-business-days-in-current-month-with-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Using this post's suggested answer with a slight edit, how can I edit this to display the current workday and total workdays in the month?

Here is my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/acm_webdev/pen/VdpNZQ) attempt.

HTML:

```
<h3>Get workdays in current month with JavaScript</h3>
<p>Current Day: <span id="currentDay"></span></p>
<p>Total Days: <span id="totalDays"></span></p>
```

JS:

```
function isWeekday(year, month, day) {
    var day = new Date(year, month, day).getDay();
    return day !=0 && day !=6;
}
function getWeekdaysInMonth(month, year) {
    var days = daysInMonth(month, year);
    var weekdays = 0;
    for(var i=0; i< days; i++) {
        if (isWeekday(year, month, i+1)) weekdays++;
    }
    $('#totalDays').html(weekdays);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution; should be pretty self-explanatory:

```js
const holidays = [
  [7, 4], // 4th of July
  [10, 31] // Halloween
];

var d = new Date();
var currentDay = d.getDate();
var year = d.getYear() + 1900;
var month = d.getMonth();
var total = 0;
var done = 0;
for (var day = 1; day <= 31; day++) {
  var t = new Date(year, month, day);
  if (t.getMonth() > month) break; // month has less than 31 days
  if (t.getDay() == 0 || t.getDay() == 6) continue; // no weekday
  if (holidays.some(h => h[0] - 1 === month && h[1] === day)) continue; // holiday
  total++; // increase total
  if (t.getDate() <= currentDay) done++; // increase past days
}
document.body.innerHTML = `Today is weekday ${done} of ${total}.`
```

The loop goes through all days of the current month and counts all weekdays and past weekdays.

Edit: added (incomplete) holiday array and check

Comment: Thanks! This method worked well.
Follow up question - what could be written to include a leap year and govt holidays? Would I need to set up variables for each and have for loop check for those variables?

Comment: @apexturtle The code already accounts for leap years, but in order to not count holidays you'd have to add an array of them and compare dates accordingly. It gets a bit complicated with holidays like Easter that aren't fixed, but it's probably possible to grab those dates from some API.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my crack at it!

The first bit creates an array with every day of the month in it:

```js
var d = new Date();
d = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 1);
var month;
function setMonth() {
  month = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 0).getDate()+1; i++) {
    var _d = new Date(d);
    month[i-1] = new Date(_d.setDate(_d.getDate() - _d.getDay()+i));
  }
}

setMonth();

console.log(month);
```

and the second part counts every workday in it:

```
var totalWorkdays = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
    let day = month[i].getDay();
    if (day == 1 || day == 2 || day == 3 || day == 4 || day == 5) totalWorkdays++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to make a solution by solving this step by step and keeping each step as simple as posible.

```js
// Returns true if date is week day
function isWeekday(date) {
  const day = date.getDay();
  return day !=0 && day !=6;
}

// Get dates of all work days in one month
function getWeekdaysInMonth(month, year) {
  return getDaysInMonth(month, year).filter(isWeekday)
}

// Get dates of all days in one month 
function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
  const firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
  const lastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
  
  return getDaysInRange(firstDay, lastDay);
}

// Get dates between 2 dates
function getDaysInRange(start, end) {
  const r = [];
  for(let dt = start; dt <= end; dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1)) {
      r.push(new Date(dt));
  }
  return r;
}

console.log(getWeekdaysInMonth(0, 2018)); // Get workdays for JAN 2018
```

Hope this helps to make it easier to reason about!

Answer (score 0):

This returns all business days if you input the first day of the month '01/07/18'.  It excludes federal holidays through 2020.

```
function day_of_week (date) {
  let weekday = ['Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday']

  return weekday[date.getDay()]

}

function formatDate (date) {
  let d = new Date(date)
  let month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1)
  let day = '' + d.getDate()
  let year = d.getFullYear()

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day

  return [year, month, day].join('-')
}

function calculate_business_days (inputDate, holidays) {

  Date.prototype.daysPerMonth = function () {
    let d = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth() + 1, 0)
    return d.getDate()
  }

  let date = new Date(inputDate)
  let transitionDays = date.daysPerMonth()
  let businessDays = []

  for (let i = 1; i < transitionDays + 1; i++) {

    let nextDay = new Date(inputDate)
    nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + i)
    let day = day_of_week(nextDay)
    if (day !== 'Saturday') { // exclude Saturday
      if (day !== 'Sunday') { // exclude Sunday
        if (holidays.indexOf(formatDate(nextDay)) === -1) { // exclude holidays through 2020
          businessDays.push(nextDay)
        }
      }
    }

  }

  return businessDays

}

let start_of_month = '06/01/2018'
let business_days_june = calculate_business_days(start_of_month, holidays_through_2020())
console.log(business_days_june)


/** output in console.log()
 * 
 [
   Mon Jun 04 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Tue Jun 05 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Wed Jun 06 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Thu Jun 07 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Fri Jun 08 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Mon Jun 11 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Tue Jun 12 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Wed Jun 13 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Thu Jun 14 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Fri Jun 15 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Mon Jun 18 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Tue Jun 19 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Wed Jun 20 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Thu Jun 21 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Fri Jun 22 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Mon Jun 25 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Tue Jun 26 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Wed Jun 27 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Thu Jun 28 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
   Fri Jun 29 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT)
 ]
 * */
```