# Is there an Excel WORKDAY.INTL function equivalent in Javascript/Googlescript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to find the nth workday from the current month? I know that google sheet has the function WORKDAY.INTL to get the date of the workday specified in the parameters

```
= WORKDAY.INTL(start_date, work_days, [weekends],[holidays])
```

Is there a way to write a Javascript or a google script function that does the same function as the above formula?

For example, to find the 3rd workday date of the current month.

Comment: No, there is not a `GAS` function to do that. But there is certainly a way to do it using JavaScript. I found many posts in stackoverflow, but you have to do your own research on that.

Comment: In short, there is no specific javascript function that does the same. Note that this is an `international` version of the `WORKDAY` excel function allowing to specify your weekends.

Comment: I searched `StackOverflow` and there is no specific javascript function to emulate the `excel` function `WORKDAY.INTL`. The excel function returns the date giving `a start` date and a number of `work days` either forward (positive) or backwards (negatives) and ignores the `weekends`. `Weekends` here can be specified using the option `[weekend]` that can be programmed and not fixed for Saturday and Sunday (i.e. here in Qatar the weekend is Friday and Saturday and other countries have different weekends). And of course, an additional option to specify `holiday days` as an array.

Answer (score 1):

Adding what Marios said in the comments but as an answer so it has more visibility.

Google Apps Script does not have such utility. The way of doing it is using JavaScript. There is already some answers in the JavaScript tag ([for example this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50807325/14779804)).

Comment: The reference post does not really do what the excel function `=WORKDAY.INTL(start_date, days, [weekend],[holidays])` in excel. The excel function is indeed very helpful and powerful.